# Как открыть порт в wsl2 + docker

Tags: docker, wsl

Поднял wsl2, установил там docker
Развернул на определенном порту сайт.
Теперь с виндовой машины по адресу localhost: сайт открывается.

Как сделать так, чтобы сайт открывался в локальной сети?
Сейчас с другим машин в локальной сети этот порт не открывается.

Заметка. Если поднимать докер не в wsl, а через docker-desktop, то порт доступен в локальной сети.

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
    php-fpm:
        container_name: ${PHP_CONTAINER}
        build:
            context: docker/php-fpm
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:/var/www
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=${REMOTE_HOST} remote_port=9004 remote_enable=1 remote_log=/var/www/xdebug.log"
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
    nginx:
        build:
            context: docker/nginx
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:/var/www
        ports:
            - ${FRONTEND_PORT}:82
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
```

Comment: Какой командой подняли сервис?

Comment: sudo service docker start

Comment: Перефразирую: какой командой подняли контейнер?

Comment: docker-compose up

Comment: Тогда выкладывайте docker-compose файл

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Да, вижу, спасибо. Тогда предположу, что нужно копать в сторону открытия портов в брандмауре, роутере и других возможных шлюзах на пути к вашему сервису, запущенному в докере.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй прокинуть порты через netsh
Примерно так:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3000 connectaddress=<WSL IP>
```

При перезапуске систем IP WSL поменяется. Делаем так:

```
1. netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=3000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0
2. netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3000 connectaddress=<WSL IP>
```

Как вариант можно написать скрипт для автоматизации процесса